# Yahoo YUI 2 - Rich Text Editor - how do I change the titlebar of the Editor to another string value?

Tags: javascript, editor, yui, yahoo, rtf

I'm using the Yahoo YUI 2 rich text editor. I would like to change the `titlebar` of the editor window from its default value of `"Text Editing Tools"` to a different value... one that fits with the page the editor is placed on.

I saw this example from the YUI 2.x Forum -

```
myEditor.toolbar.set('titlebar', 'Foo');
```

But that doesn't work for me.

My editor is created like this -

```
        var OpeningTextEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('OpeningText', {
            height: '300px',
            width: '522px',
            dompath: false, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
            animate: false, //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows
            handleSubmit: true                
        });

            //***** T H I S   L I N E   D O E S N'T   W O R K ******
            //OpeningTextEditor.toolbar.set('titlebar','Opening Text');

        OpeningTextEditor.render();
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax? I don't know why else it wouldn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these seem to work:

```
OpeningTextEditor.get('toolbar').titlebar = 'Opening Text';
```

or

```
OpeningTextEditor._defaultToolbar.titlebar = 'Opening Text';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The 1st statement of code didn't work...not sure why...but the 2nd one did:) I don't think I would've ever figured out how to set the titlebar, so thank you very much for your help!