# Rich Text Editor (YUI Simple Text Editor used) not sending data to next page

Tags: javascript, yui, rich-text-editor

I am using a simple text editor from YUI, but when I click submit the code in the textarea/editor is not sent to the next page. I want to be able to receive it on the subsequent page and then store it in a DB(MySql). I have wasted lot of time already. Please help.
HTML FILE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.9.0/build/container/container_core-min.js&2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js&2.9.0/build/editor/simpleeditor-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/editor/assets/skins/sam/simpleeditor.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css">
<!-- Utility Dependencies -->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> 
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/element/element-min.js"></script> 
<!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/container/container_core-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
<!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
<script>
YAHOO.util.Event.on('submit', 'click', function() {
myEditor.saveHTML(); 
var html = myEditor.get('element').value;
});
(function() { 
        var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom, 
        Event = YAHOO.util.Event; 

        var myConfig = { 
                height: '200px', 
                width: '900px', 
                dompath: true,                   
            }; 
        myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor('msgpost', myConfig); 
        myEditor.render(); 


})();       
</script>

</head>

<body class="yui-skin-sam">
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="msgpost" id="msgpost" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return myDoSubmit()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `saveHTML()` method you used does not seem to save the value to the `textarea` element. And because the browser doesn't care about YUI Editor and just submits what is there already in the `textarea` (which is null), it submits the input as null..

You should set the value of the `textarea` to the editor value so the browser will submit that value instead of null.. Which can be achieved using this little line:

```
document.getElementsById("msgpost").value = html;
```

See this working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAK7Y/) I made for you.

However you had `HTML` syntax errors too. The `onSubmit` attribute should be on the `form` element not the submit button.

And listening to the event is not practical when you can simply call a function when the form submits.. (See the JsFiddle)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to ask one more thing. I have a simple form with a button tag. Whenever I click button the form gets submitted, even though I have not asked for it.
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
 <div id="main">
   <button>Add Row(s)</button>   
 </div>
</form>... Please help me figure it out.. It is strange and I have restarted server but still.

Comment: When you set the button type to `Submit` it will submit the form ,which it's in it. You don't have to do any `Javascript` that is the default function of that button. If you don't want to automatically submit try the `Button` type.

Comment: That's the point..  here m using button(button tag) but still it is submitting. Am I doing something wrong?... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw an example on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233662/yahoo-yui-2-rich-text-editor-how-do-i-change-the-titlebar-of-the-editor-to-a).

Basically, add this to myConfig: `handleSubmit: true`

myConfig will then look like this:

```
var myConfig = { 
            height: '200px', 
            width: '900px', 
            dompath: true,
            handleSubmit: true  
        };
```